# Nuxt add middleware to all pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to add a middleware to all the pages in a Nuxt app?

Besides adding it to the layouts. Because it requires to remember that every new layout must have a middleware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

You can add it in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['your-global-middleware'],
},
```

This one will look for a middleware in your `middleware` directory, as for any regular middleware and apply it on all your app.

Answer (score 6):

In Version 3 of nuxt you can simply add the suffix .global to your filename.
like so:

```
middleware/yourfile.global.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt3 global middleware can be defined as '/middleware/..filename.global.ts' and can use 'useState' composable inside middleware to handle redirection using loggedIn information like as follows:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const { user, loggedIn } = useState('auth').value

    if(!loggedIn && !user) {
        return navigateTo('/auth/login')
    }
})
```

The middleware then automatically intersect before each route change. No need to tell each pages as their page meta option manually.

But it has a problem for initial entry in Nuxt Application. So, need to handle also the entry point in such way that can bypass this global middleware when entering initial page.

You can call another "Named Route Middleware" for entry page as a guest or something like this.